# How to read Matlab 7.3 and greater cell arrays using pytables

Tags: python, cell-array, pytables

I'm trying to read a matlab (7.3 and greater) cell array (Nx1 cell) using pytables.
I can get the table, but when trying to read it (table[:]), I'm getting this error message:

> array(/table_name (UnImplemented(1, 154)) ''   NOTE: The UnImplemented
>   object represents a PyTables unimplemented dataset present in the ...
>   HDF5 file.  If you want to see this kind of HDF5 dataset implemented
>   in PyTables, please contact the developers.

So I guess I need to contact the developers? Is there any other way to read matlab (7.3 and greater) cell arrays?

Comment: `h5py` might have better success reading this `matlab` structure.  `scipy.io.loadmat` handles `matlab` up to 7.2.  But even with that cells and structures are hard to translate into python equivalents.

Comment: latest pytables should read that format